# Stored Procedure- Special Account

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement to execute a stored procedure and fetch data from a table. I need to create an account in SQL and use the same. (SQL 2005)

I need to create an account in SQL. I can create that. But How do I Use that account to run the stored procedure and the table(to get data out of table)

Thank you

Comment: SQL? SQL Server? MySQL? Or just with SQL syntax?

Comment: How do you do which part?  Same what?

Comment: Sorry all my question wasn't clear.. I have edited it now.

Comment: Maybe something about `EXECUTE AS`...

Answer (score 0):

I depends upon which client you use, but you can simply change your connection string to use standard security

e.g.

> Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

See [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) for your specific needs